Does it matter how far out you cast your line?
When casting out a line in WEBFISHING, the longer you hold left click the further out you cast. Does it matter how far you cast out your line? Will you catch different fish if you cast your line further out into the water?

Sort of. Occasionally there will be circular ripples in the water. If you cast your line near one, you will near instantly hook a fish as catch rate is boosted by 2500%. Catch rate will also increase if you cast near a meteor spot. Additionally, different bodies of water will have different types of fish.

Aside from that, I haven't noticed any differences based on how far you cast your fishing line.

While reading through the wiki for the weather/rain question you posted, I came across this in the wiki: "Fishing on a ripple will boost the catch rate by 2500%, which effectively causes the player to instantly hook a fish." So it is slightly nuanced, but has the same overall effect.

@Daemons Edited answer to include this info.

@Daemons What exactly is the benefit of changing the extension of the .jpg to .webp?

@Joachim Faster image loading.
